# Exception: Could not find driver | OpenPSA | postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to setup OpenPSA using this [link](https://openpsa2.org/resources/installing-openpsa/).

I am stuck with this step:

```
./vendor/bin/openpsa-installer midgard2:setup
```

Whenever I try to execute the command.

It shows me this error.

[image]

Here is the `midgard-portable-default.inc.php` file:

```
<?php
use midgard\portable\driver;
use midgard\portable\storage\connection;

$basedir = dirname(__DIR__);

require_once $basedir . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$schema_dirs = [$basedir . '/schemas/'];

$driver = new driver($schema_dirs, $basedir . '/var', '');

// CHANGE PARAMETERS AS REQUIRED:
$db_config = [
    'memory' => true,
    'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
];

connection::initialize($driver, $db_config, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Mysql driver in configuration instead of the postresql ones.

Comment: Just  edited the question... check the configuration file, I have used "pdo_pgsql".

Comment: Ok. Then check `php.ini ` on your server if you properly enable PDO.

Comment: Yeah ..Its over there. Uncommented "pdo_pgsql" & "pgsql"